# Differentiate iOS and Android Firebase Authentication Users

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

We are using firebase project using FirebaseUI for user authentication. 
Single Firebase Project is used for both iOS and Android ( as they access same database ).

There is no issue in integration, how can we identify registered users whether they are iOS or Android from Authentication Screen?

We can have firebase-analytics to capture some sort of flag to indicate the difference but was looking for simple way to identify them using console or in code while registering without using analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase auth is not support custom data in register process. So using console is not possible. A workaround for this case I usually do is saving custom data in Firebase Database. Ex:

```
{
“users”: {
“Ab232....”:{
“device”:”IOS”,
“user_name”:”phapli”
}
}
}
```

Comment: interesting.. will sure try that.. i hope something inbuilt is provided by google that we can find out